# Dockerfile & docker-compose configuration for Rails5 as RESTful API, nodeJs and React.js

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-5

I need help to understand the best configuration for my app architecture. 
I find myself banging against the wall when I look around the internet for answers.

**Architecture**

```
Databases: 

 - Postgres x2

Backend:

 - Rails5 used as Restful API

 - Phyton used for data analysis services

FrontEnd

 - React.js

 - Node.js
```

**How the architecture will interact**

UI built in React.js with the support of Node.js will talk to the BackEnd Rails app via API. Rails app won't be using any VIEWS
The Data collected from the UI will POST to the Rails APP which will use Phyton algorithms to analyze and return a result (whatever it will be)

User data will be stored in the Postgres DB.

All this will run on an AWS Ubuntu instance via Dockerization (Kuberneties or ECS/EKS)

**PROBLEM TO FIX**

I'm trying to set up locally on my mac a Dockerfile and docker-compose in order to have the above working.

In the Dockerfile configuration (please correct me if I am wrong), I will need to:

```
 - Run Ruby

 - Run Node.js

 - Run Phyton
```

In the docker-compose file (please correct me if I am wrong), I will need to:

```
 - Install and run Nginx

 - Install Passenger for Rails

 - Open the ports to communicate

 - Anything I need for the Databases? (DB will be cloud-based)
```

**MY QUESTIONS**

> 1. How do I connect my local apps (react.js and Rails) to the containers in local machine?
> 2. How do I wrap everything ready for deploy on staging server?
> 3. Can someone write the Dockerfile and docker-compose for me to achieve that kind of architecture?
> 4. Do I need to use volumes or networks in this case?

Many thanks in advance

George

Answer (score 0):

For the Question #1 you can install VS code and add Docker Extension

[image]